# Find max score by arranging books in boxes

Tags: algorithm

Given an array p which stores the number of pages in a book and an array s which stores the size of boxes. number of books = sum of sizes of all boxes.
Now we can put the books in the boxes. Given any such arrangement. for each box calculate (max+min) where max is the book with max number of pages and min is the book with min number of pages.
In case the box could contain only one book we calculate (max +max) The final score will be the sum of all the scores. The goal is to maximize the score and return this score. What approach could we use for this?
Ex: pages=[7,1,1,12], box=[3,1] first box should have [7,1,1] and second [12] yielding a score of (7+1) + (12+12)=32

**My Thoughts:**
I initially thought of sorting the pages list in descending order and the box size list in ascending order. Now if there is a box of size 1 pick the front element of the pages list and add it to it as that will help maximize the score. For boxes of further sizes, pull out the exact number of books as the box size and calculate the score.
But this strategy doesn't work in general

Answer (score 1):

Assuming sum of box size = length of `pages` array.

Notice that it is always better to assign books with largest page number available into different boxes.
So, suppose we have `b` boxes, and `p` books and `b <= p` (because for `b > p` the answer is obviously to put 1 book to 1 box).
**Splitting the largest `b` books to `b` boxes** will contribute to max value of each boxes better than if we put any two largest b pages into one box.

For example

```
|1st largest|2nd largest|...|(b)th largest|
```

is better than

```
|1st largest|2nd largest|...|((b-1)th & (b)th largest)|(b+1)th largest|
```

because the `(b-1)th` and `(b)th` largest page cannot both contribute to max of a single box.

Now that we have put `b` largest pages into the boxes and get the maximum value for each boxes, what about the minimum value?

We want the minimum value of each box to be as large as possible. We can "waste" some books with small number of pages by filling the box with the largest space first before filling the next box. So, **for the remaining `(p-b)` smallest books: pick the box with the largest size `s`, put smallest `s` books in this box, and repeat until we run out of books.**

Why is this optimal? Let's say we already put `(i-1)` smallest books to random boxes and we want to assign book with the `(i)th` smallest pages into one of the boxes. If we put this book into an empty box, it will immediately become the minimum value of this new box. But if we put this book into a non-empty box, it will always be more than or equal to the minimum value of the non-empty box. Because we already put a book with value less than or equal to the `(i)th` book. Thus by filling in the largest box first until it's full, we "waste" more minimum values, giving us a larger minimum value for the next box.